# Apollo GraphQL One-Off Query?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm upgrading my code from using a 6-months-plus-old version of Apollo, to using the current version.

This code used to work for doing a one-off query, but no longer works:

**SET UP**

```
const subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(`ws://localhost:5000/`, {
    reconnect: true
});

// Create a normal network interface:
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    },
    transportBatching: true,
    batchInterval: 10

});

// Extend the network interface with the WebSocket
const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(
    networkInterface,
    subscriptionClient
);

const ApolloClientWithSubscribeEnabled = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions,
    queryTransformer: addTypename,
    dataIdFromObject: (result) => {
        if (result.id && result.__typename) { // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
            return result.__typename + result.id; // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
        }
        return null;
    },
    shouldBatch: true,
    initialState: window.__APOLLO_STATE__, // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
});
```

**ONE-OFF QUERY**

```
getUserInfoForCurrentUser() {
    const userIsLoggedIn = Meteor.userId() ? true : false;
    if ((userIsLoggedIn) && (this.originatingUser == null)){
        const localThis = this;
        const userID = Meteor.userId();
        this.client.query({
            query: GET_USER_INFO_QUERY,
            variables: {userID: userID},
        }).then((result) => {
            localThis.originatingUser = result.data.getUserData[0];
        });
    }
}
```

Searching the Apollo docs, I see [a reference to one-off queries](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api.html), but I haven't yet found docs showing how to do it. Searching the Apollo sample app, "GitHunt-React-master", I also haven't yet found an example of how to do this.

What is the correct way to do a one-off query in the current 1.x version of Apollo?

Comment: What's the error you're getting if any? I think the issue is with how you're setting up the network interface and the client. I see lots of things in there that are now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, @helfer. I'm getting an error, "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Network request failed with status 200 - "OK"" But that doesn't matter- I'm using deprecated code. What's the right way to do it? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: That's a really weird error message, but I remember just reading that code a few days ago, and I think it indicates that the response isn't JSON parseable. You should check in the network tab of the developer tools to see what response your server is sending and add it here. I don't think this issue has anything to do with one-off queries, so you may want to update the title.

Comment: Thanks for this info. The current code has worked perfectly for 6+ months on the old Apollo libraries. Just as a place for me to start, is there a link to an example showing current Apollo code that does one-off queries?

Comment: I do want to know how to do one-off queries in the current Apollo, as it is something I do in a number of components in my app. The error message I'm currently getting is not a concern, because I will discard the old code in favor of the latest patterns. I would just like to find some sample code in the current Apollo for doing one-off queries, as per the title of this thread. :)

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't think this is related to one-off queries. You could convince me otherwise if you show that it works when you do client.watchQuery, but not when you run the same query with client.query. :)

Comment: Okay, I think what you're saying is that my one-off query code is okay as is. I will look into other causes for the anomaly.